# PHP Delete Link Unlinks Files from Folders but Doesn't Remove Row from MSSQL Table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, row, unlink

When the link is clicked this function is put into place. The purpose of this function is to delete the image and PDF file from my website's folders, and remove the specified row from my MSSQL table. This function only removes the image and PDF from the folders but does not delete the row.

Here is the function's code:

```
if ($_GET['del'] == 'true') {
   // cast id as int for security
   $product_code = $_GET['product_code'];
   $file = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("select product_img_name from products where id = $product_code"));
   unlink("img/$file[0]");     
   $file38 = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("select specsheet from products where id = $product_code"));
   unlink("specsheets/$file38[0]"); 
   // delete row from table
   $sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_code = '$product_code'";
   $result = mssql_query($sql, $conn);
   } // end if del
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your last WHERE condition. `product_code = '$product_code'` must be `id = '$product_code'`

Additionally, you can fetch two columns with a single query:

```
$row = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("select product_img_name, specsheet from products where id = $product_code"));
unlink("img/$row[0]");
unlink("specsheets/$row[1]");
```

Comment: What if the two columns had separate names and you fetched both with one query?

Comment: By column names I meant the data inside of each column.

Comment: I see your point and realized a mistake in my answer. Sorry for that. You should access elements by `$row[0]` and `$row[1]`. Now fixing the answer

Comment: I think a question deserves upvote if it is unique on stackoverflow, not related to a specific code and very well written. For an answer, it should also be well written, should cover all aspects, should give relevant clues (if any). Also I think I adversely affected by your offer..

Comment: I believe it is unique. Most questions on Stack Overflow are derived from experience with specific code. I believe both are well written and are quite punctual. Your answer covers all aspects of my question.(It solved my question.) It also provided a learning experience with your additional knowledge on shortening my code by using a single query. I don't see how asking for an exchange of up votes would affect you negatively either, as I am simply just asking a question.